# Override ToString() in asp.net c#, basics. Doesn'twork

Tags: c#, asp.net, overriding, tostring

Hi I have the Default aspx. 
I want to test overriding default methods like to ToString().
Whenever I use ToString(), I thought with following code it has to add "my text";? why not?

```
public partial class test : System.Web.UI.Page
{

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return base.ToString() + "my text"; 
    }


    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        object test = 3333;
        Response.Write( test.ToString());
    }
}
```

Comment: You may want to name your class using PascalCase, too. Here you can find some Microsoft's advices on how to name things if you need it: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xzf533w0%28VS.71%29.aspx

Comment: of learning/understanding oop/c# I think yes.

Comment: Ok, I'm not sure what you're trying to do. `Default.aspx` has **nothing** to do with "default methods like to ToString". It is just a page that loads. What is your goal here?

Comment: Hmm... I'm wondering that other are understanding it. Now after several answers I wan't to know why it's not possible to override the ToString() method of an object.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As everyone said you are overriding the wrong method. If I understand correctly what you are trying to accomplish, then maybe an extension method is more appropriate :

```
public static class ObjectExtensions
{
    public static string ToCustomString(this object instance)
    {
        return instance.ToString() + "whatever";
    }
}

public partial class test : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        object test = 3333;
        Response.Write(test.ToCustomString());
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 because I think you understood what the OP is trying to do.

Comment: Yes he did. So I see, it won't be possible to override the ToString() function of an object to use it with same Methodname in my class.

Comment: It appears the problem is an incorrect understanding of virtual methods and what happens if you override them.

Comment: I wonder whether the OP thought that naming the class and the local variable the same (“test”) would matter.

Answer (score 6):

You want to call

```
this.ToString();
```

or simply

```
ToString();
```

What you did created an `object` with the name `test`, not the type `test`, and called the default `ToString` of `object` (well, of `int`, in this case).

Alternatively, if you want to create another page with the type `test`:

```
test newPage = new test();
test.ToString();
```

Comment: Or delcare `test mypage = new test();`

Answer (score 1):

The object `test` is not your class, it's just an object.

Answer (score 0):

I would like you to rewrite your code in

```
protected void TestWrite(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    test test = new test();

    System.Diagnostics.Trace.Write(test.ToString());
}
```

and then write

```
protected void TestWrite(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    test test = new test();

    object testObject = test;

    System.Diagnostics.Trace.Write(testObject.ToString());
}
```

You will call ever the overwritten tostring method.

We call it "dynamic binding" in object oriented programming. Please be confident about this subject if you want to understand what really means an Object in computer science.

And... as Unsliced said :

> "The object test is not your class,
>   it's just an object."

Good Luck